# Combining and aligning multiple divs into a single shape

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a hexagon using CSS. There are a number of questions about this already, but in my specific case I need it composed of 3 identical shapes that are different colors.

There are 2 specific requirements:

1. The overall size of the hexagon must be controllable by a single value. In my case that is the width of the `.hexagon-wrapper` class
2. The hexagon shape must be centered horizontally and vertically within it's parent (`.hexagon-wrapper`), and that wrapper must also be centered horizontally and vertically within its parent (the outermost div)

You'll notice there are some problems with my attempt:

1. The 3 pieces that make up the hexagon arent tightly aligned,
   and the overall shape starts to break apart when you change
   `.hexagon-wrapper width`
2. I'm using some magic numbers to translate the individual pieces, and they don't guarantee that the pieces will stick together after resizing, nor do they really guarantee that the elements are perfectly centered horizontally and vertically

Is there an easier way to do this, or some simple math that I'm missing? Basically, how do I keep the pieces together, and how do I ensure everything is centered?

I did consider creating a 3D cube and using `transform3d` to ensure everything sticks together, but I *do not* want to go with this approach because I have had many anti-aliasing issues when using `transform3d` and want to avoid that altogether

```css
.hexagon-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.hexagon-part-red {
  position: relative;
  width: 27.85714285714286%;
  padding: 0 0 32.16760145166612% 0;
  transform: translate(112%, -50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
}

.hexagon-part-yellow {
  position: relative;
  width: 27.85714285714286%;
  padding: 0 0 32.16760145166612% 0;
  transform: translate(-49%, 25%) rotate(0deg) skewY(30deg);
  background: yellow;
  margin: auto;
}

.hexagon-part-blue {
  position: relative;
  width: 27.85714285714286%;
  padding: 0 0 32.16760145166612% 0;
  transform: translate(-69%, 25.1%) rotate(60deg) skewY(30deg);
  background: blue;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="hexagon-wrapper">
    <div class="hexagon-part-red"></div>
    <div class="hexagon-part-yellow"></div>
    <div class="hexagon-part-blue"></div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easier idea where you don't need any complex calculation and a lot of transform:

```css
.hexagon-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hexagon-part-red,
.hexagon-part-yellow,
.hexagon-part-blue {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.hexagon-part-red:before,
.hexagon-part-yellow:before,
.hexagon-part-blue:before {
  content: "";
  padding-top: 115.47%;  /* 100/cos(30deg) */
}

.hexagon-part-red {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  background: red;
  clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%);
}

.hexagon-part-yellow {
  transform: skewY(30deg);
  transform-origin: left;
  background: yellow;
}

.hexagon-part-blue {
  transform: skewY(-30deg);
  transform-origin: right;
  background: blue;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon-wrapper">
  <div class="hexagon-part-red"></div>
  <div class="hexagon-part-yellow"></div>
  <div class="hexagon-part-blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had to remove the `clip-path` and use transforms instead just so things like borders work properly, but otherwise this works great. Thanks!